# Console prints out the function, not the value

Tags: javascript

Hello I am a new coder and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my logic. I'm making a tip calculator, so I created an object (tipCalculator) and I have two properties (bills) and (percentage), I want to iterate over bills.length and multiply each element by an element in percentage array according to the if statement. When i try to call it and print this to the console, it just prints out the function. Can someone explain why this wouldnt work? thanks :)

```
var tipCalculator = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    percentage: [.2, .15, .1],
    calcTip: function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++){
        if(this.bills < 50){
            return this.bills * this.percentage[0];
        } else if (this.bills >= 50 && this.bills <= 200){
            return this.bills * this.percentage[1];
        } else {
            return this.bills * this.percentage[2];
        }
    } 
    }
};

tipCalculator.calcTip();
console.log(tipCalculator.calcTip)

//and heres my current results: 

ƒ (){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++){
        if(this.bills < 50){
        console.log(this.bills * this.percentage[0]);
        } else if (this.bills >= 50 && this.bills <= 200){
```

//Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ```console.log(tipCalculator.calcTip())```

Comment: Because you are not console logging the result/output of the function with `tipCalculator.calcTip`, you are logging _the function itself_. To log the output, you would want `console.log(tipCalculator.calcTip())`.  Note that the `()` are added to invoke the function.  Also, I believe there are some other problems with this function at a glance-- hopefully now that you understand how to invoke it and log the result you can start tackling those issues next.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks yes I fixed the console log but now its logging 'NaN' is there something wrong with the function?